# How to get value from a JIRA REST API in Postman

Tags: rest, postman, jira, jira-rest-api

I am completely new in JIRA system. For some development purpose I need to use some JIRA REST APIs. Please see an example of the API below:

```
https://jira.sw.abcd.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=xyz%abcd%efg%12345%20
```

Now when I hit an API from browser (e.g. Chrome) I get the result perfectly. But when I try to hit via Postman it's giving me the following message with status code

> 400 bad request

```
{
    "errorMessages": [
        "The value 'abcd' does not exist for the field 'xyz'."
    ],
    "errors": {}
}
```

I searched and found that I need authorization. So I provided my username and password in the

> "Authorization" section where the type is "Basic Auth"

But still the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your url looks weird %a??

Comment: In your encoded jql, the '%' is important in order to understand the problem. Please share the real jql with us.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ@stuck actually the real query was like this in a search input field
xyz = "abcd efg 1234". I copied from the URL from browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Postman may be transferring your JQL a little bit different than what you are expecting.

Checking the JIRA REST API documentation:

- https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues-6291606/

It's possible to see that most of the examples are using "=" signs in the query params of the URL.

So JIRA would be expecting you to send something like this:

```
  http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=fred
```

Note that the query params *do accept the = sign after the jql.*

So first step would be to sort out the JQL you want to use and put it as it is in the query string.

Additionally, the document offers the option to use a POST where you can specify in the payload the JQL you want:

- https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues-6291606/#query-using-post

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: Let us hear from you the solution you found in the end.
It may help the community

Comment: Hi, for some reason I am unable to tag you. Anyway, I had to add a bearer token for authentication. Then it worked.

Comment: That's awesome!! @ShuvoBarua ! Would you mind accepting the answer if it helped?

Thanks!